# Redux state change in componentWillMount is not be recognized in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, redux, lifecycle, react-redux

Need to load my main component and, in case a localstorage with the pair value "logged: true" exists redirect to "/app" using react-router.

I am using react-redux and this is my code:

```
class Main extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
// Return true in redux state if localstorage is found
      this.props.checkLogStatus();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
// redirect in case redux state returns logged = true
      if(this.props.logStatus.logged){
          hashHistory.push('/app');
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <App centered={true} className="_main">
        {this.props.children}
    </App>
    );
  }
}
```

My redux action:

```
checkLogStatus() {
  // check if user is logged and set it to state
  return { 
      type: LOGIN_STATUS,
      payload: window.localStorage.sugarlockLogged === "true"
  };
}
```

But when the component gets to the componentDidMount stage, my redux state has still not been updated.

Y manage to get this to work by using:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if (nextProps.logStatus.logged && nextProps.logStatus.logged !== this.props.logStatus.logged){
          hashHistory.push('/app');
      }
  }
```

But I am not sure it is the most elegant solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using `componentWillReceiveProps` is the way to go here since your logStatus object is being passed in as a prop that is being changed.

There is a more elegant way to this using the [Redux-thunk middleware](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) which allows you to dispatch a function (which receives `dispatch` as an argument instead of the object actions. You can then wrap that function in a promise and use it in `componentWillMount`.

In your actions file:

```
updateReduxStore(data) {
  return { 
      type: LOGIN_STATUS,
      payload: data.logInCheck
  };
}

validateLocalStorage() {
  ...
}

checkLogStatus() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            validateLocalStorage().then((data) => {
                if (JSON.parse(data).length > 0) {
                    dispatch(updateReduxStore(data));
                    resolve('valid login');
                } else {
                    reject('invalid login');
                }
            });
        });
    };
}
```

Then in your component:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.checkLogStatus()
      .then((message) => {
          console.log(message); //valid login
          hashHistory.push('/app');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err); //invalid login
      });
}
```

Redux-thunk middleware is made for such use cases.